# Can't load BiodiversityR in RStudio on Mac

Tags: r, macos

I installed Biodiversity, and run `library(BiodiversityR)`, then it said, "Loading required package: tcltk". The loading lasted for 10 hours. I then restart the mac and tried again, but it happened again.

Answer (score 0):

**Too long; didn’t read**

The problems is usually related to your R version or package version, so update your R first. If it doesn’t work, update your packages. If install.packages() doesn’t give you most recent version, go to cran site and download the file, unzip it, and replace the old package file in your library.

**What I have done**

I downloaded and installed [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) and `library(BiodiversityR)` again, it gave me some message this time (great!) as follows.

```
# Loading required package: tcltk
# Loading required package: vegan
# Loading required package: permute
# Loading required package: lattice
# This is vegan 2.6-4
# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘BiodiversityR’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
#   namespace ‘Rcmdr’ 2.7-2 is being loaded, but >= 2.9.1 is required
# In addition: Warning message:
#   package ‘BiodiversityR’ was built under R version 4.3.1
```

The error is related to “Rcmdr”, seems that it is out of date, so I did `install.packages("Rcmdr”)`, but there are some warnings as follows.

```
# Installing package into ‘/Users/Kang/Library/R/x86_64/4.1/library’
# (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
# Warning in install.packages :
#   lzma decoder corrupt data
# 
# There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
#   binary source needs_compilation
# Rcmdr  2.8-0  2.9-1             FALSE
# 
# installing the source package ‘Rcmdr’
# 
# trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rcmdr_2.9-1.tar.gz'
# Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 9407419 bytes (9.0 MB)
# ==================================================
#   downloaded 9.0 MB
# 
# ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/Users/Kang/Library/R/x86_64/4.1/library’ for modifying
# Try removing ‘/Users/Kang/Library/R/x86_64/4.1/library/00LOCK-Rcmdr’
# Warning in install.packages :
#   installation of package ‘Rcmdr’ had non-zero exit status
# 
# The downloaded source packages are in
# ‘/private/var/folders/7p/vbfp82515bbdqt0khfk6ks9w0000gn/T/RtmpDofZ5K/downloaded_packages’
```

Seems that Rcmdr has been installed, however the version is not the newest. If we go back to the last error message after I tried to load BiodiversityR, it said “namespace ‘Rcmdr’ 2.7-2 is being loaded, but >= 2.9.1 is required”. To confirm that, I checked the version of the package.

```
packageVersion("Rcmdr")
# ‘2.7.2’
```

So I guessed a more recent version Rcmdr was needed. I then tried to install the package from Github, but it didn’t work.

```
devtools::install_github("https://github.com/cran/Rcmdr")
```

I went to the cran [site of the package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcmdr/index.html) and downloaded the “Rcmdr_2.9-1.tgz” file and unzipped it, and moved it into the folder of my R packages.

If you don’t know the directory to the folder, run `.Library` in your RStudio. I checked the version of Rcmdr, and finally it worked!

```
packageVersion("Rcmdr")
‘2.9.1’
```

Now I `library(BiodiversityR)` again and got the following message.

```
# Loading required package: tcltk
# Loading required package: vegan
# Loading required package: permute
# Loading required package: lattice
# This is vegan 2.6-4
# BiodiversityR 2.15-4: Use command BiodiversityRGUI() to launch the Graphical User Interface; 
# to see changes use BiodiversityRGUI(changeLog=TRUE, backward.compatibility.messages=TRUE)
# 
# Warning message:
#   package ‘BiodiversityR’ was built under R version 4.3.1
```

There is a warning message, but seems that it worked! At least, it worked on my Mac, though my R version is lower than 4.3.1.

Just in case some unexpected errors happen again, I decided to update my R. I went to the [site for R](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) and downloaded the most recent version and installed it, restarted RStudio. However, before I was trying to `library(BiodiversityR)` again, there was a message. Now, there is a funny story … it asked me if I want to install some required package like “BiodiversiryR” and “ggplot2”. What I had been doing for the last two days?! Anyway, I said yes, and it installed or updated many packages. Again, I `library(BiodiversityR)`. A old-fashion window popped up and asked me if I want to install some packages required for Rcmdr. I clicked yes. By the way, in this step, I also got the following message.

```
Loading required package: tcltk
Loading required package: vegan
Loading required package: permute
Loading required package: lattice
This is vegan 2.6-4
also installing the dependencies ‘coda’, ‘arm’, ‘mi’, ‘mvtnorm’, ‘TH.data’, ‘commonmark’
```

After the installation, here it was again, `library(BiodiversityR)`.
No any message. No error, no warning.
It worked.
Again, what I had been doing for the last two days …